# The code is giving me syntax error even though I couldn't find any

Tags: python, tkinter, syntax

I am getting a syntax error that I cant find. Just a while ago it was working totally fine but then it suddenly started giving me error even though I never changed anything in that line of code. Can you take a look plz.

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
# Variables
HEIGHT = 320
WIDTH = 500

# Functions:
def calculation():
    global last
    lst = []
    e1 = En1.get()
    e2 = En2.get()
    e3 = En3.get()
    e4 = En4.get()
    e5 = En5.get()
    lst.extend([e1,e2,e3,e4,e5])
    print (list)



# Window:
canvas = Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1, relheight = 0.8, relwidth = 0.8)

# Widgets:
button = Button(frame, text='Calculate', padx = 50, pady = 3, command=calculation()
# Entries:
En1 = Entry(frame, bg = 'white')
En2 = Entry(frame, bg = 'white')
En3 = Entry(frame, bg = 'white')
En4 = Entry(frame, bg = 'white')
En5 = Entry(frame, bg = 'white')
# Label:
lb1 = Label(frame, text='How much does person A weight:', padx = 10, pady = 5, anchor = 'w')
lb2 = Label(frame, text='How much does person B weight:', padx = 10, pady = 5, anchor = 'w')
lb3 = Label(frame, text='How long is the chair:', padx = 10, pady = 5, anchor = 'w')
lb4 = Label(frame, text='How far is person A sitting from left side', padx = 10, pady = 5)
lb5 = Label(frame, text='How far is person B sitting from right side', padx = 10, pady = 5)
# Widget's position:
button.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
# Entries:
En1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
En2.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
En3.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
En4.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
En5.grid(row = 9, column = 0)
# Labels:
lb1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
lb2.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
lb3.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
lb4.grid(row = 6, column = 0)
lb5.grid(row = 8, column = 0)

# Result:
result = Label(frame, bg = 'white')
result.grid(row = 2, column = 1, rowspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

If I run this code it gives me the following error.

```
    File ".\Second.py", line 32
    En1 = Entry(frame, bg = 'white')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

By the way, it is not only line 32 that gives me this error. I tried to comment out the lines with error and it seems like Every single widget in the code gives me the same syntax error. I tried to find it but I coulndn't.

I am a newbie in python so quiet possibly I have done some dumb mistake I am unaware of.

Comment: `button = Button(frame, text='Calculate', padx = 50, pady = 3, command=calculation()` is missing a closing parenthesis `)`. You also shouldn't call the function when passing to command, so that line should be: `button = Button(frame, text='Calculate', padx = 50, pady = 3, command=calculation)`

Comment: Usually, missing parentheses will incur a syntax error on the following line from where the closing bracket should be (because python is interpreting the next line as part of the same function call (or class instantiation in this case)

Comment: You `calculation` function is also a little confused, because you have `global last` but no `last` outside the function, and then you `print(list)` which will either give you `<class 'list'>` this, or if you've clobbered the built-in `list` will print that, but that's no relevant to the calculation function, as far as I can see.

Comment: Oh. thanks i got it.

Comment: Yeah the function is messed up because I copied it from another code. For now I was just trying to make the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button = Button(frame, text='Calculate', padx = 50, pady = 3, command=calculation()
```

There doesn't seem to be a closing parenthesis here. Could that be the issue?

Comment: You are the one answering the question. *Could* it?

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much. But why did the error was showing me a different line.

Comment: @AlexMRTY The argument list can be split across multiple lines (that is, parentheses induce implicit line continuation). If there had been a comma before `EN1`, it would have looked to the parser like a perfectly valid keyword argument for the call to `Button` that began on the previous line. *That* is the actual syntax error: the missing comma. The fact that you meant to finish the call expression (but did not) is a *semantic* error that the compiler cannot catch.